# Writing a plugin(Indexing) for Nutch

Tags: nutch

I am writing a plugin for nutch which parses text and creates a new field depending on text. For this the plugin which I am writing implements IndexingFilter. I am following the tutorial as in [here](http://florianhartl.com/nutch-plugin-tutorial.html) (which is similar to that in nutch wiki). I have followed exactly as it is mentioned and I am successfully able to build the plugin. However I do not see the new index being added. Well I am beginner so I am not sure if I am looking at right place.

I did normal crawling using the command

```
bin/nutch crawl urls -dir crawl -depth 3 -topN 5
```

And then I checked in crawldb and segment using command

```
bin/nutch readdb crawl/crawldb/ -dump crawlContent
bin/nutch readseg -dump crawl/segments/* segmentAllContent
```

I do not see the new field added here. Am I doing it right? Or is there any command I need to run. Thanks in advance.

Code:

I copied the directory structure of urlmeta plugin and made couple of changes.

plugin.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <plugin id="myPlugin" name="Add Field to Index"
      version="1.0.0" provider-name="your name">

    <runtime>
       <library name="myPlugin.jar">
     <export name="*"/>
       </library>
    </runtime>

    <extension id="org.apache.nutch.indexer.myPlugin"
       name="Add Field to Index"
       point="org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingFilter">
      <implementation id="myPlugin"
        class="org.apache.nutch.indexer.AddField"/>
    </extension>
  </plugin>
```

build.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <project name="myPlugin" default="jar">
     <import file="../build-plugin.xml"/>
  </project>
```

And other code is same as in the link mentioned.

Comment: It is working now. If anyone else is facing similar problem then I can post the changes I had to make.

Comment: You can and should answer your own question if you have the solution. It makes absolutely no sense if anyone would ask you for that.

Answer (score 2):

Check that if the value of plugin.includes in nutch-default.xml contains myPlugin,like this:

myPlugin|protocol-http|urlfilter-regex|parse-(text|html|js)|index-basic|query-(basic|site|url)|summary-basic|scoring-opic|urlnormalizer-(pass|regex|basic)

PS:
You can and should answer your own question if you have the solution,just add some comment after this.